# upload photo/album that will visible only to me by default

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am uploading photos to facebook using graph api.
Is there a way to make this photos un-visible by default and only after the user approve them than the photos will be visible to his friend (like it was done when my application was in development mode).

Thanks,

Comment: If you do not have the publish_stream permission then the photos will need to be approved before other users can see them.

Comment: I have publish_actions and user_photos, and I must use both to upload my album https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/455200654611142/ . is there any property that I can add or config from my application management so my photos will have to be approved before publish?

Comment: publish_actions includes publish_stream permission; I've done this previously - it used to be the case that if you do not have publish_stream / publish_actions then the photo will still be uploaded but will not be publicly visible unless the user goes to the album and approves it. If you have an app already setup for testing I would encourage you to try this. If not, I can put an app together quickly, test and submit an answer.

Comment: Hi...The main problem is that if I don't use publish_actions there is a facebook api bug as described here : developers.facebook.com/bugs/455200654611142 . this bug creates deplicated album

Comment: Hi...If I remove the publish_actions permissions I still see it on the session even after I un-install an install my new app again. I think the session remembers my old permissions. is there a way to clear the session ?